# Use desktop as bluetooth headset

Tags: arch-linux, android, bluetooth

My desktop's speaker is much better than my phones, so I want to use my desktop speakers in place of my cellphone's. It is inconvenient for me to use USB or the audio jack, so I am left with Bluetooth. I have paired my phone using `bluetoothctl`, but when trying to connect I get this:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 00:00:00:00:00:00 
Attempting to pair with 00:00:00:00:00:00
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 Connected: yes
Request confirmation
[agent] Confirm passkey 000000 (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 Modalias: bluetooth:a000Aa000000000
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 UUIDs: 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00000a0a00aa
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 UUIDs: 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00000a0a00aa
...
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 UUIDs: 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00000a0a00aa
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 UUIDs: 000000000-0000-1000-8000-00000a0a00aa
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 RSSI: -75
[bluetooth]# connect 00:00:00:00:00:00 
Attempting to connect to 00:00:00:00:00:00
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

I have replaced my mac address with `00:00:00:00:00:00`, but the actual mac address does match the one reported by my phone. I have done the same with the pairing pin, the Modalias and the `UUIDs`, although I have no clue what the last two are.

Comment: Shall we suppose you're looking for help configuring Bluez?

Comment: If it allows me to route the audio from my phone to my desktop speakers, then yes!

Comment: All I know thus far is that Bluez audio is highly experimental. I never tried this but I am highly interested to know. Have you tried [this](https://gist.github.com/joergschiller/1673341) ?

Comment: No, nor do I know how to set it up.

Comment: The link explains how to setup A2DP. Bluez must be [configured](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth) beforehand.

Comment: I just saw [this link](https://gist.github.com/joergschiller/1673341), and I will be trying to set it up.

Comment: Have you installed and enabled the `pulseaudio` plugin? That's usually what gives me trouble. I never cared too terribly to look into why - but more often than not `pulseaudio --kill; sudo systemctl restart bluetooth ` *`(something I usually <tab-complete>)`* `; pulseaudio --start` seems to work. I think the trouble arises when the `bluetoothd` puts the `hci` dev to sleep after awhile - and `pulseaudio` will often do the same.

Comment: The `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` file doesn't seem to exist. Should I create a new one, and put the `Enable=Source` into a new file?

Comment: This question doesn't specify whether the task is playing files from a smartphone's audio/music library, or setting up a loud half-duplex speakerphone.

Comment: Have you tried [Blueman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Blueman)? It works fine on my laptop.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to two modules from `pulseaudio`[*](https://github.com/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/tree/master/src/modules/bluetooth) which bond with `bluez` this is actually really easy to do, now.

Install the requisite packages:

```
sudo pacman -S bluez bluez-utils pulseaudio-bluetooth
```

Add your user to the `pulseaudio` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G pulseaudio $USER
```

Turn on or restart the bluetooth daemon:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Enable your bluetooth device:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

If you have more than one bluetooth device, you should replace `hci0` with the correct identifier, which can be found by running `hciconfig` with no arguments.

Now we can connect our devices using the interactive `bluetoothctl` utility.

First, we will make our Arch machine discoverable by its hostname:

```
$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF arch [default]

[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered

[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful

[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Discoverable: yes
```

Your Arch box should be discoverable now for your phone. Select the device and return to the your prompt to confirm:

```
Request confirmation
[agent] Confirm passkey 748794 (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA ...
... snipped ...
[agent] Authorize service 0001... (yes/no): yes
... snipped ...
[agent] Authorize service 0001... (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Discoverable: no
```

I've had some disconnect issues that were resolved by simply running the `trust` command after connecting.

```
[phone]# trust
[CHG] Device FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA Trusted: yes
Changing  trust suceeded
```

That's it, you should be able to play audio through your desktop speakers.

Comment: It works, but is there anyway to improve latency?

Comment: the hci utils are now in AUR via bluez-utils-compat